# Unable to open apache website from internet of my Raspberry Pi B+ V2

Tags: linux, apache, raspberry-pi2

I setup Apache server on my Raspberry Pi.
In LAN it is working fine.
But when I tried to open it with my public IP it simply gets Timed Out.
I opened a Port : 2323
Checked on canyouseeme.org
[image: Screen shot of canyouseeme.org with SUCCESS notification]

Means I have configured `port forwarding` correctly...?

Now I am trying to open this page with url: `122.175.144.237:2323` it shows `Time Out` Error.

I have 2 devices

1. Binatone ADSL2/2+ Modem+router
2. Tenda N3 Wirless N150 WiFi Router

and my Raspberry Pi is connect with WIFI with static IP `192.168.192.99`

I searched for this problem but till now not found any appropriate solution.

Is there any problem in configuration of Apache? or I missed some configuration. or it is because of apache restricting to open page with public IP or not allowing to open over internet.

Is there any way..?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the port is open on the external interface of your router, that doesn't necessarily imply that port forwarding is setup correctly, just that the router isn't flat-out rejecting that traffic. Also, as you have a second wireless router in your network (that is probably itself running NAT), you must also have port forwarding setup on that as well.

Apache must also be configured to answer for the virtual host it is being addressed as. It *should* answer on it's IP with a default page, but without knowing specifics I couldn't rule it out.

That should get you started, but at this point you still need to narrow the problem down quite a bit before proceeding.